# Elasticsearch pagination spillage

Tags: php, elasticsearch, pagination

I run this query with a php client:

```
$params["body"] = [
            "from" => $page,
            "query" => ["filtered" => ["filter" => ["bool" => [
                            "must" => [
                                ["term" => ["user" =>  $userId]],
                                ["term" => ["activitySeen" =>  false]]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "size" => 5,
        ];
```

I have a total of 3 documents that should be returned. Searching with $page = 0 returns 3 documents as expected.

However, searching with $page = 1 returns 2 documents and with $page = 2 returns 1 document and the search with $page = 3 returns 0 documents.

What might be the issue?

If I play with page sizes the spillage is still there: last legitimate page of values is spilled on to the next page with one less value!

I'm testing it either on one or two nodes with 3 primary and 1 replica shards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`from` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html?q=from) is not a page but an offset, so what you get is correct.

- Starting at offset 0 (i.e. `$page = 0`), you get 3 documents
- Starting at offset 1 (i.e. `$page = 1`), you get 2 documents
- Starting at offset 2 (i.e. `$page = 2`), you get 1 documents
- Starting at offset 3 (i.e. `$page = 3`), you get 0 documents

You should just rename `$page` to `$from` so the variable name better matches the meaning.

Comment: For some reason I assumed "from" was indicating a page number. Thanks for quick reply.